# Upgrading 12.04. on ancient mac book ('07)?

Tags: dual-boot, upgrade, mac

I just succeeded to install 12.04 alongside OSX 10.5.8 on an old MacBook. It was a very long & winding road. At some point, I also tried to install 12.10, without success at all., stuck at tux logo.

machine is mac book 3.1 (late'07), pre-unibody (polycarbonate) intel core duo 2.1GHz, 2GB ram,120 GB hitachi hdd. Optical bay doesn't work.

Also, it won't boot from external media, so I had to partition only one internal hdd, mount iso on one of partitions, run live session from there, and make installation on other partition of same hdd. iso image had `/cdrom` as mounting point. I made `/` as mounting point for partition with actuall instalation, and unmounted one containing iso img via terminal, just prior to finishing installation. it worked. Had refit installed under osx.

My question is, would 14.04 work on that machine, since it is offering me to upgrade in update menu?

Comment: I'm sorry but we can't help you with the information you provided. What machine is this? What is its hardware? What kind of problems did you have when you tried to install 12.10? Where did it fail? Have you tried booting from a live 14.04 CD? Please [edit] your question and add these details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

14.04 works perfectly after upgrading by option offered in update menu of previous 12.04.5.
Been watching terminal closely during the installation, there were some warnings about possible problems, but after rebooting only pre-existing i-sight missing firmware problem was reported, which suits me even better, haha.
Everything else works just fine, as for now. Computer itself seems to work a bit faster and definitely smoother than before. May be the issue of recognizing second core, as @DaveEmme mentioned in previous answer.
Dual booting via option key without problems.

Answer (score 0):

Not your machine, but FWIW, I have:

White Macbook 5.2 (2009), 2 GHz Intel Core 2 Duo, 2 GB 667 MHz DDR2 SDRam, 120 GB HDD

and Kubuntu 14.04 runs just fine on it. Earlier versions of Ubuntu only recognized one of the two cores. That was somewhat slow, but that's since been fixed.

I used to use refit, but had some sort of booting problem at one time. I ran bootrepair to fix it. Now if I just power up the machine, it boots into GRUB and thence to Kubuntu. If I want to run OS X 10.6, I just hold down the Option key at power up and can select Mac OS. Quite handy for me.